# Display a RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I'm trying out the new `RecyclerView` in Android Lollipop and I'm stuck.

I'm trying to receive a list, with an icon and a `TextView` to the right of the icon, inside a `Fragment`.

[I found this great tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/) on how to set up a `RecyclerView`. I have followed every point and only changed the `item_layout.xml` to fit my needs.

The project builds without any errors but when it launches on my device I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fredrikaldgard.materialcolors/com.fredrikaldgard.materialcolors.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

I've tried to google the problem but I'm quite an amateur with Android development.

Here's my `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // 1. get a reference to recyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // 2. set layoutManger
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // this is data fro recycler view
    ItemData itemsData[] = { new ItemData("Indigo",R.drawable.circle),
            new ItemData("Red",R.drawable.color_ic_launcher),
            new ItemData("Blue",R.drawable.indigo),
            new ItemData("Green",R.drawable.circle),
            new ItemData("Amber",R.drawable.color_ic_launcher),
            new ItemData("Deep Orange",R.drawable.indigo)};


    // 3. create an adapter
    MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);
    // 4. set adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    // 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

And my `MyAdapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ItemData[] itemsData;

public MyAdapter(ItemData[] itemsData) {
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    // - get data from your itemsData at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

    viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());


}

// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
    }
}


// Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData.length;
}
}
```

**Edit:** Here's the `Fragment`

```
public class ColorsFragment extends Fragment {

    public ColorsFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colors, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

What has possibly gone wrong?

Comment: Do you still have a RecyclerView with id list in your xml layout file? If not, the recyclerView variable will be null in step 2.

Comment: Yes, I have a RecyclerView in my xml with the id "list".

Comment: Should have been clearer: in the `activity_main.xml` file, right?

Comment: @stkent Well, I use a nav-drawer which opens an activity when i click on one  of the items in the drawer. My activity_main.xml contains a FrameLayout with the drawer inside it. My RecyclerView is inside an XML file called fragment_color.xml.

Answer (score 66):

This was asked some time ago now, but based on the answer that @nacho_zona3 provided, and previous experience with fragments, the issue is that the views have not been created by the time you are trying to find them with the `findViewById()` method in `onCreate()` to fix this, move the following code:

```
// 1. get a reference to recyclerView
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);

// 2. set layoutManger
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

// this is data from recycler view
ItemData itemsData[] = { new ItemData("Indigo",R.drawable.circle),
        new ItemData("Red",R.drawable.color_ic_launcher),
        new ItemData("Blue",R.drawable.indigo),
        new ItemData("Green",R.drawable.circle),
        new ItemData("Amber",R.drawable.color_ic_launcher),
        new ItemData("Deep Orange",R.drawable.indigo)};


// 3. create an adapter
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);
// 4. set adapter
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
// 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

to your fragment's `onCreateView()` call. A small amount of refactoring is required because all variables and methods called from this method have to be static. The final code should look like:

```
 public class ColorsFragment extends Fragment {

     public ColorsFragment() {}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colors, container, false);
         // 1. get a reference to recyclerView
         RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

         // 2. set layoutManger
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

         // this is data from recycler view
         ItemData itemsData[] = {
             new ItemData("Indigo", R.drawable.circle),
                 new ItemData("Red", R.drawable.color_ic_launcher),
                 new ItemData("Blue", R.drawable.indigo),
                 new ItemData("Green", R.drawable.circle),
                 new ItemData("Amber", R.drawable.color_ic_launcher),
                 new ItemData("Deep Orange", R.drawable.indigo)
         };


         // 3. create an adapter
         MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);
         // 4. set adapter
         recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         // 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
         recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

         return rootView;
     }
 }
```

So the main thing here is that anywhere you call `findViewById()` you will need to use `rootView.findViewById()`

Comment: replace this with getActivity() .

Comment: You could also return the recyclerview from the fragment 'onCreateView' because essentially the fragment is now a RecyclerView

Comment: Im getting an error with `MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);` it says  MyAdapter(android.context.Context, List<>) in MyAdapter cannot be applied to (List<>)

Comment: Thanks bruh. I'm just getting back into native Android development, after creating my first app years ago targeting v2.3.3, and yeah... let's just say a thing or two has changed. OH LAWD

Answer (score 36):

You should retrieve `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment` after inflating core View using that View. Perhaps it can't find your *recycler* because it's not part of Activity

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist_tracks, container, false);
    final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(c);
            c.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I tried to replace my code inside my Fragment with yours but I got a problem with

"final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();" 

It gives me an error: Required "android.support.v4.app.FragmentActitvity" Found "android.app.Activity". I have compiled the v4 support library in my project.

Comment: You can use any activity, you don't have to use support library if don't need it

Comment: What do you mean by "use any activity"? I'm using the support library for a nav drawer anyway.

Comment: I meant any subclass of activity class. Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: I have to apologize, I'm not very good at complicated things like Fragments. What exactly should I write instead of "final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();"? When I replac FragmentActivity with just Activity the error disappears but I still have this error: http://imgur.com/amSWNWc

Comment: mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

Comment: may i ask why you setting the adapter in a runnable?

Comment: Adapter should be set on UI thread. Data is loaded on another thread and we can not interact with UI on non-ui thread. Please notice that using raw threads is usually bad practice. I think kotlin coroutines are new way to do so properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct layout, and that the RecyclerView id is inside the layout. Otherwise, you will be getting this error. I had the same problem, then I noticed the layout was wrong.

```
    public class ColorsFragment extends Fragment {

         public ColorsFragment() {}

         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

==> make sure you are getting the correct layout here. R.layout...

             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colors, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. And got the solution when I use this code to call context. I use Grid Layout. If you use another one you can change.

```
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),1));
```

if you have adapter to set. So you can follow this. Just call the getContext

```
  adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), myModelList);
```

If you have Toast to show, use same thing above

```
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error in "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this will work.

**HappyCoding**