# Recyclerview in fragmnet using volley json data?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

please any one explain RecyclerView in fragment using volley to get json data.
Already i refered below link coding [Google recyclerview in fragment](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4)

this is my first project in android, so i cannot understand that coding.
Please any one help me.

My fragmnet Coding:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false);
    orderLists = new ArrayList<>();

    getProgressData();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    adapter = new ProgressOrderListAdapter(orderLists, this);
    adapter.clearAdaptor();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return recyclerView;
}

private void getProgressData(){
    String mobilecustomertoken = SharedPreferencesManager.readPreferenceString("MobileCustomerToken", "D/N");
    JSONObject progressData = new JSONObject();
    try{
        progressData.put("mobilecustomertoken", mobilecustomertoken);
        JsonObjectRequest progressObject = new JsonObjectRequest(1, Common.OrderDetails + "progress", progressData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject progressResponse) {
                Log.d("Responseprogress", progressResponse.toString());
                try {
                    int status = progressResponse.getInt("status");
                    if(status == 1) {
                        progressOrderProgress(progressResponse);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Response", "PROGRESS ERROR");
            }
        });
        progressObject.setShouldCache(false);
        ServiceBellApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(progressObject);
    }
    catch (JSONException localJSONException){
        localJSONException.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}

private void progressOrderProgress(JSONObject progressResponse) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = progressResponse.getJSONArray("orderdata");
    OrderList orderListModule = new OrderList();
    for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++){
        JSONObject orderData = result.getJSONObject(i);
        orderListModule.setPackage_name(orderData.getString("package_name"));
        orderListModule.setOrderdate(orderData.getString("orderdate"));
        orderListModule.setServicedate(orderData.getString("servicedate"));
        orderListModule.setServicetime(orderData.getString("servicetime"));
        orderListModule.setOrderid(orderData.getString("orderid"));
        orderListModule.setOrdstatus(orderData.getString("ordstatus"));
        orderListModule.setOrderamount(orderData.getInt("orderamount"));
    }
    orderLists.add(orderListModule);
}
```

My adapter code:

```
public class OrderListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<OrderList> List;
private FragmentPending mContext;

public OrderListAdapter(List<OrderList> List, FragmentPending context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.List = List;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_list_view, null);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    // this is where the each item is inflated.

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    OrderList orderListsPos = List.get(position);
    // this is where the data for each item is assigned
    holder.textViewPackageName.setText(orderListsPos.getPackage_name());
    holder.textOrderdate.setText(orderListsPos.getOrderdate());
    holder.textServicedate.setText(orderListsPos.getServicedate());
    holder.textServicetime.setText(orderListsPos.getServicetime());
    holder.textOrderid.setText(orderListsPos.getOrderid());
    holder.textOrderamount.setText("Rs." + orderListsPos.getOrderamount());
    holder.textStatus.setText(orderListsPos.getOrdstatus());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return List.size();
}

public void clearAdaptor() {
    List.clear();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewPackageName;
    public TextView textServicedate;
    public TextView textServicetime;
    public TextView textOrderdate;
    public TextView textOrderid;
    public TextView textOrderamount;
    public TextView textStatus;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewPackageName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        textOrderdate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderdate);
        textOrderid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderno);
        textOrderamount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderprice);
        textStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderstatus);

    }
}}
```

Comment: Which part in that link you didn't understand?

Comment: concept 5. Style each view and add a RecyclerView

Comment: Thats pretty much Straight forward.. Designing each row? in that which part are you having doubt?

Comment: My doubt is how to connect recyclerview and fragment

Comment: i have one question for you, Have you ever worked with `RecyclerView` on `Activity` ?

Comment: I think **16th** point on that is very much clear in terms on `Fragment`

Comment: No this is first time

Comment: where i mention recyclerview id

Comment: ok If thats the case i will post an Answer.. Please wait

Comment: Please view my answer..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a RecyclerView in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621060/display-a-recyclerview-in-fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need four things

> 1 ) layout that holds the each recycler view layout item
>
> 2 ) A view holder for creating each layout
>
> 3 ) A Model Class to holds the data
>
> 4 ) Recycler Adaptor which deals with the data for the Each Layout item

FIrst create a layout item

for eample lets create a single view with only `TextView` in it

**XML**

each_item.xml

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

and lets now create a view holder
i will post both code for the view holder and RecyclerAdaptor

```
public class Adaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptor.ViewHolder> {
  List<Model> List = Collections.emptyList();
  private Context mContext;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  public Adaptor(Context context, List<Model> List) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.List = List;

 }


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_item, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    // this is where the each item is inflated.

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WinnersViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Model mModel = List.get(position); 
    // this is where the data for each item is assigned
    holder.nameView.setText("" + mModel.getName());
  
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return List.size();
}

public void clearAdaptor() {
    List.clear();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView nameView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.nameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        
    }
 }
}
```

Now the model class

```
public class Model {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
 }
}
```

Now the back end is done, Lets implement it on the Fragment

```
List<Model> List = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Adaptor adaptor;

public Fragment() {
    // constructor of fragment
    // Required empty public constructor
}
```

in the `onCreatView()` get the id of recyclerView

```
 View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
 mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView .findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

and then pass the data to the `Adaptor` by creating its object

```
    adaptor = new Adaptor(getContext(), List);
    adaptor.clearAdaptor();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adaptor);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

You are done now, only thing pending is if you are accessing data form server call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `adaptor = new Adaptor(getContext(), getList());` where the `getList()` returns the Model data and do not call `adaptor.clearAdaptor()` .

hope this helps ..

**EDIT**
you can two ways infalte the each layout item .. one is above and second is in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.each_item, null);
```

Comment: I get error in inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); this line in adapter

Comment: Finally i get this error java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called. U have any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code and possible LogCat too.. It might be some error related to JSON Volley @vinothkumar

Comment: @vinothkumar if this answer has helped , appreciate by up voting.. Hopefully i can fix the current issue too

Comment: @vinothkumar there are some awesome , simple and Light weight libraries to handle web requests, the error is mainly due to `you are not closing the response body after opening` , Do you still want to use this `JsonObjectRequest` or may i suggest some good and easy to use libraries to handle web requests.

Comment: @vinothkumar there are some possible and obvious issues with your code

Comment: Give any example friend

Comment: Do upvote if you found my answer usefull.. @vinothkumar

Comment: @vinothkumar try [this](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) link or alternative [this](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/) link

Comment: if you are still using this JsonObjectRequest then call the `getProgressData();` below the adaptor initialization and call `adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged()` before the catch clause inside the onResponse

Comment: i'll try this menthod

Comment: @vinothkumar also pass `getActivity()` to the adaptor not `this`

Comment: @vinothkumar No logCat ??

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue? Rerun the code and check again

Answer (score 1):

Check this link It is really helpful for beginners for understanding concepts from start to mastering the RecyclerView.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView

Hope this helps you to understand recycler view concepts.

Comment: i'll check this example

Comment: i want recyclerview in fragment friend

Answer (score 0):

## RecycerView + Fragment + Volley

[image]

**Fragment Code:**

```
public class DogListFragment extends Fragment{

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager llm;
    private DogListAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<DogModel> dogList;
    private Context context;

    public static DogListFragment getInstance(){
        return new DogListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dogList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new DogListAdapter(context, dogList, this);
        getListFromServer();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dog_list, parent, false);
        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        llm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    public void getListFromServer(){

        String url = "https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images/random/20";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("message");

                        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                            String imageUrl = array.getString(i);
                            dogList.add(new DogModel(imageUrl));
                        }
                        adapter.updateDataSet(dogList);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               }
            }
        );

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

## Full code

[Woof Repository](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Woof)

It has the following implementations

- Fragment communication via interface
- Reusing fragment by
  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG)
- Which lifecycle method should have API call so that it is called just
  once
- How to save RecylcerView state in Fragment (Scroll position + content)
- Pagination in RecyclerView
- Rest Calls (Volley)
- Image Rendering (Glide)
- JSON Parsing