# How to use recyclerView or list view in a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, fragment

I want to use a list(recyclerView or list view) in my app.i have used ahBottom navigation in my application and i want to show a list view when clicked one of them.
please help me.

mainactivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> list_poems;
private AHBottomNavigation ahBottomNavigation;
private ArrayList<AHBottomNavigationItem> ahBottomNavigationItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private AHBottomNavigationViewPager viewPager;
private ViewpageAdapter adapter;
private ArrayAdapter adapter_lists;
private Database db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list_poems = db.list_title();
    adapter_lists = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_poems);

    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);



    ahBottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.Ahbottom);
    ahBottomNavigation.setColored(false);
    ahBottomNavigation.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    viewPager = (AHBottomNavigationViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);

    AHBottomNavigationItem item1 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("اشعار", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp), Color.parseColor("#f2ff50"));
    AHBottomNavigationItem item2 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("جستجو", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp), Color.parseColor("#f2ff50"));
    AHBottomNavigationItem item3 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("تنظیمات", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp), Color.parseColor("#f2ff50"));
    ahBottomNavigationItemArrayList.add(item1);
    ahBottomNavigationItemArrayList.add(item2);
    ahBottomNavigationItemArrayList.add(item3);

    ahBottomNavigation.addItems(ahBottomNavigationItemArrayList);

    ahBottomNavigation.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#53D9FF"));
    ahBottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    ahBottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frm, fragment).commit();
        }
    });

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    adapter = new ViewpageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

viewpageradapter:

```
public class ViewpageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<Fragment_instance> array_frag = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewpageAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
    array_frag.add(Fragment_instance.newInstance("علاقه"));
    array_frag.add(Fragment_instance.newInstance("جستجو"));
    array_frag.add(Fragment_instance.newInstance("تنظیمات"));
}
@Override
public Fragment_instance getItem(int position) {
    return array_frag.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return array_frag.size();
}
```

Fragment_instance:

```
public class Fragment_instance extends Fragment {

private static String frag_key = "fragment title";

public static Fragment_instance newInstance(String title) {
    Fragment_instance fragmentInstance = new Fragment_instance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(frag_key, title);
    fragmentInstance.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentInstance;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621060/display-a-recyclerview-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

I think his demo project is perfect for studying. You can try to set up and explore. 
https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation